# How to add image to file format .mp3 on a Mac?

Tags: macos, file, mp3

I use a Mac and have artwork I would like to add as images to sound .mp3 file.

I am aware that I can create a .mov file using QuickTime media player which is already built-in on my Mac, but I’d just like to attach art, not translate the whole file into a new format.

What tools or scripts or apps can do this task?

Comment: With the Music app on MacOS you can right click on a song and select "Get Info", then a popup opens and you can select "Artwork", on the bottom you see a button with "Add Artwork".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several places you can do this:

- within iTunes. Simply right click, select Get Info, then select the artwork tab and select “Add Artwork”
- from Get Info (Finder). Right (Option) click the file and select Get Info. Choose Artwork, then select Add Artwork. Select the art work you would like to embed.
- in [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/). Go to Media Information screen <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>  which will bring up a window of all the tags including artwork. Simply drag your artwork to add it.
- via a tag editor like [Music Brainz Picard](https://picard.musicbrainz.org/). You can easily add the Artwork by dragging it to the artwork “field” in the editor and save it.
- command line via [`ffmpeg`](https://ffmpeg.org/)

  ```
  ffmpeg -i musicfile.mp3 -i coverart.png -c copy -metadata:s:v title="Album Cover"-metadata:s:v comment="Album Art " musicfile.mp3
  ```

Comment: I tried both approaches using Finder and VLC. none of them worked (I have macOS Catalina). I looked through all menus and cannot find any way to add the track cover to the tracks. Can you please add more details to those instructions? "Choose Artwork", "Add Artwork"? Where are that menu options? I use VLC as default player for my mp3s if that matters.

Comment: yea no "Choose Artwork" from Get Info in MacOS Moterey either.  `ffmpeg` says "Unable to find a suitable output format for 'comment=Album Art ' comment=Album Art : Invalid argument". No dragging artwork support in VLC from Cmd-I screen.

Comment: @okram In Finder drag the artwork on top of the generic music icon top left in the 'Get Info' window.